# New variable stripe_subscription required for Cashier with Laravel 5

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, stripe-payments, laravel-5.1, laravel-cashier

I'm upgrading from Laravel 4.2 to Laravel 5.1.  I have a Stripe account that works with Cashier in my Laravel 4.2 version that I built watching a Laracast on Stripe and Cashier.  However, in Laravel 5.1 a new table column is required called "stripe_subscription."  I tried researching the Stripe documentation, the Cashier documentation and the Laravel documentation, but couldn't find anything about what this variable is or does.

After simply adding it to my database with a new migration, it looks like Stripe is up and running again with Cashier in my Laravel 5.1 version.  However, I was wondering if anyone knows what this variable does or where I can learn more about it.  I just guessed that it should be a string, which I was really unhappy about having to guess, but it seemed to work.

Here is some code relevant to this variable from my project:

From my migration:

```
$table->string('stripe_subscription')->nullable();
```

From the Cashier file Billable.php:

```
 public function setStripeSubscription($subscription_id)
    {
        $this->stripe_subscription = $subscription_id;

        return $this;
    }


public function getStripeSubscription()
    {
        return $this->stripe_subscription;
    }

public function deactivateStripe()
    {
        $this->setStripeIsActive(false);

        $this->stripe_subscription = null;

        return $this;
    }
```

I'm just noticing it does actually say that stripe_subscription is a string in the php file, but I'd rather see something in formal documentation about it.  Further, as far as I can tell, this variable is unnecessary because there is also a "stripe_plan" variable.  The "stripe_subscription" variable contains a random string, while the "stripe_plan" variable is the name of the plan, like "monthly" or "yearly."

If anyone can give me some guidance on where I can learn more about this variable and how to work with it, I'd appreciate it.